# How to write string not containing null byte character using python

Tags: python, string, file, file-handling, nul

How to write a string in a file ensuring that there is no nul byte character in a string in python?

```
f.write(x1+','+x2+','+x3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `'\x00'` your input string by an empty character.

In your example that would look like this :

```
data = x1+','+x2+','+x3
data = data.replace('\x00' , '')
f.write(data)
```